# Login-error page not displayed when using python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am using [social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) (part of python-social-auth) to implement Facebook login for the users of my Django site. I have a requirement that users must be found in the local user database before they can log in with Facebook. I have replaced the auth_allowed-part of the authentication pipeline, to perform this check:

```
def auth_allowed(backend, details, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if not backend.auth_allowed(response, details) or not is_registered_user(response, details):
        raise AuthForbidden(backend)
```

where `is_registered_user()` is a custom function that checks whether the user exists locally.

My problem is that **the users are not redirected to the login error URL**, if this check fails and the `AuthForbidden` exception is thrown. Instead, the site returns a 500.

The error-page URL is configured as follows in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = "/"
```

I am using Django CMS, so I have also tried implementing middleware that overwrites `SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware` (which is supposed to handle the `AuthForbidden` exception in a standard setup) to return a CMS-page instead of an URL from settings.py but this middleware is not invoked in the process, as far as I can see.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved the problem: I accidentally used

```
social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware
```

instead of

```
social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware
```

when referring to the exception-handling middleware. The bug was most likely introduced during an upgrade from `django-social-auth` to `python-social-auth`/`social-app-django` some time ago.